# Is there a way to use result of a variable across the stored procedure which is declared in 'for' block in oracle sql query?

Tags: oracle, plsql

My code is something like this below.

```
DECLARE
  empName varchar(20);
BEGIN
  FOR emp_details in(SELECT * FROM emp_ids where condition)
  LOOP
    emp_name(emp_details.id, empName);
    dbms_output.putline('The employee ' || empName || ' has id ' || emp_details.id);
  END LOOP;
  --want to print other details which is returned by select query, 
  --but it should be outside of loop
END;
```

Is there a way to use those values which is resulted from the 'for' block outside of the loop-endloop block..
is there something like making it as global, so i can use for block variables across the procedure?

Thanks in advance

```
DECLARE
  empName varchar(20);
BEGIN
  FOR emp_details in(SELECT e.id,d.dependent_name FROM emp_table e, dept_table d where e.id=d.id)
  LOOP
    emp_name(emp_details.dependent_name, empName);
    dbms_output.putline('The employee ' || empName || ' has' || emp_details.dependent_name || '(s)depends');
  END LOOP;
  dbms_output.putline('The employee ' || empName || ' id is' || emp_details.id);
END;
```

//my select query result would be.

```
e.id   d.dependent_name
1      xxx
1      yyy
```

Comment: Not with cursor `for` loop. `emp_details` variable (variable of query%rowtype data type) is defined implicitly and local to the  cursor `for` loop block. What exactly are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: Oh. okay . thanks for the reply Nicholas.

Comment: above code is just a sample one..
based on the number of rows returned by the 'select' query i will print empl.name and id for n no.of times in a loop.
other details of the same employee i want to print only one time. (so i dont need to loop it, anyhow it will print atleast once which are relevent to that employee details returned by 'select')

Comment: Example. example, example. What desired output should look like? Give us some sample of source data and how you want to "print" them.

Comment: Do not post code in the comment section. Edit your question

Comment: What do you want to happen when there is more than one match (display only first, only last, show everything)?  It seems like there should never be more than one match from your example data, which means you have no need for a loop in the first place.

Comment: in example i will never get more than one match.
But in the actual query i use, select query returns more than one row as results. that is why. if it returns 3rows as a result, i will loop only few columns from rows. remaining i will display in outside of loop

Comment: Give an example of expected output with three rows.

Comment: Thank you all for helping me at right time. I found the solution as below in answer Thank you again

Answer (score 2):

To answer your first question, you can't.  The variable is scoped to inside the loop, so you can't access it outside.  Your alternative is to declare a variable in the outer scope and then store the results from the query and use that instead.

I think this is what you're *trying* to do, but I don't understand *why* you want to.  It's going to be extremely inefficient since it's going to store the query output in an object and then iterate it twice, but at least the query itself is only is being run once.

```
CREATE TABLE EMP_TABLE (ID NUMBER);
CREATE TABLE EMP_DETAILS (ID NUMBER, EMP_NAME VARCHAR2(20));
CREATE TABLE DEPT_TABLE (ID NUMBER, DEPENDENT_NAME VARCHAR2(20));

INSERT INTO EMP_TABLE (ID) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO EMP_TABLE (ID) VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO EMP_TABLE (ID) VALUES (3);

INSERT INTO EMP_DETAILS (ID, EMP_NAME) VALUES (1, 'John');
INSERT INTO EMP_DETAILS (ID, EMP_NAME) VALUES (2, 'Bob');
INSERT INTO EMP_DETAILS (ID, EMP_NAME) VALUES (3, 'Bill');

INSERT INTO DEPT_TABLE (ID, DEPENDENT_NAME) VALUES (1, 'DN1.1');
INSERT INTO DEPT_TABLE (ID, DEPENDENT_NAME) VALUES (1, 'DN1.2');
INSERT INTO DEPT_TABLE (ID, DEPENDENT_NAME) VALUES (1, 'DN1.3');
INSERT INTO DEPT_TABLE (ID, DEPENDENT_NAME) VALUES (2, 'DN2.1');
INSERT INTO DEPT_TABLE (ID, DEPENDENT_NAME) VALUES (2, 'DN2.2');
INSERT INTO DEPT_TABLE (ID, DEPENDENT_NAME) VALUES (3, 'DN3.1');
INSERT INTO DEPT_TABLE (ID, DEPENDENT_NAME) VALUES (3, 'DN3.2');

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE T_EmpDepRow AS OBJECT 
(
  ID NUMBER, 
  EMP_NAME VARCHAR2(20), 
  DEPENDENT_NAME VARCHAR2(20)
);
/

DECLARE
  TYPE T_EmpDeps IS TABLE OF T_EmpDepRow;
  V_EmpDeps T_EmpDeps := T_EmpDeps();
BEGIN

  SELECT T_EmpDepRow(e.id, ed.emp_name, d.dependent_name)
  BULK COLLECT INTO V_EmpDeps
  FROM emp_table e
  INNER JOIN emp_details ed
    ON e.id = ed.id
  INNER JOIN dept_table d 
      ON e.id = d.id;

  FOR i IN 1 .. V_EmpDeps.COUNT
  LOOP
      dbms_output.put_line('The employee ' || V_EmpDeps(i).EMP_NAME || ' has ' ||
                          V_EmpDeps(i).DEPENDENT_NAME || '(s)depends');
  END LOOP;

  FOR j IN 1 .. V_EmpDeps.COUNT
  LOOP
      dbms_output.put_line('The employee ' || V_EmpDeps(j).EMP_NAME || ' id is ' || V_EmpDeps(j).ID);
  END LOOP;
END;
/

DROP TABLE EMP_TABLE;
DROP TABLE EMP_DETAILS;
DROP TABLE DEPT_TABLE;

DROP TYPE T_EmpDepRow;
```

This gives you the output

```
The employee John has DN1.1(s)depends
The employee John has DN1.2(s)depends
The employee John has DN1.3(s)depends
The employee Bob has DN2.1(s)depends
The employee Bob has DN2.2(s)depends
The employee Bill has DN3.1(s)depends
The employee Bill has DN3.2(s)depends
The employee John id is 1
The employee John id is 1
The employee John id is 1
The employee Bob id is 2
The employee Bob id is 2
The employee Bill id is 3
The employee Bill id is 3
```

This said, you should really explain *why* you want to do this in the first place, since this is probably not the right way to go about it.

Comment: Thank you all for helping me at right time.
I found the solution as below.
Thank you again ..

Answer (score 0):

```
tables:
employee
dependent 
policy_companies 

requirement in a procedure:
for cursor(select the details of employees, dependents and policy companies details with condition)
Loop
--print employee details
--print dependent details
--print policy companies details
end loop

Problem is: If an employee has policy in more than one company, it might return more than a row in select query(n times).
so loop is repeated for n times. but i dont want all the details to be repeated n times. I wanted only policy details to be reeated. not others two)

Solution: 
I found like create twp cursors with the little modification in the select query.
for cursor1(select the details of employees, dependents and policy companies details)
Loop
--print policy details
end loop
for cursor2(select the details of employees, dependents and policy companies details where conditions like where i will not get more than a row result)
loop
--print dependent and employee details
end loop
```